# kendo: resize window on click

Tags: windows, kendo-ui

i have a kendo window which opens an iframe form. when they submit the form and it shows the results i want the window to widen. how can i set the of the window on click of button.

```
     var window = $("#PCwindow"),
        PCopen = $("#PCopen").bind("click", function() {
            window.data("kendoWindow").center();
            window.data("kendoWindow").open();
        });

      window.kendoWindow({
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        width: "500px",
        height: "500px",
        title: "Performance Checker",
        content: "PCchecker.html",
        iframe: true
      });
```

i want the window to go to 700px wide

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
 window.data("kendoWindow").setOptions({width : 700});
```

In addition, and in order to optimize your code, I would suggest reducing the number of times that you execute `window.data("kendoWindow")` by writing it as:

```
var window = $("#PCwindow"),
        PCopen = $("#PCopen").bind("click", function () {
            window.data("kendoWindow")
                    .center()
                    .open()
                    .setOptions({width: 700});
        });
```

Comment: thank you very much. how would i call  window.data("kendoWindow").setOptions({width : 700}); from within a function

Comment: Simply do `$("#PCwindow").data("kendoWindow").setOptions({width : 700});`, it should work

Comment: thanks again really appeciate it. but i tried that. heres a link to what im building its a simply form that produces a car tuning spec based on model selected. when you submit the form i want the window to resize. but it throws an error. [link](http://projects.quayhosting.co.uk/hyperchips/data/)

Comment: you need to click the green tab in the top right to load up the window initially

Comment: thanks for the example. i think its because im trying to resize the window while it open. can this be done? Also do you know why the you cant select an item in a dropdownlist on an iPad/iphone if its in a window. its strange.